# Detrending Discrete Data

Tags: regression, discrete-data, bias

I am trying to detrend some discrete data and I am having difficulty finding a model to describe the trend. There is a number of discrete data points and there is a linear error being introduced with time. I created some representative data in excel:

Unbiased:

[image: Unbiased]

Biased data:

[image: Biased]

The discrete data here is 1,2,3 with a positive linear bias over time. Traditional least squares does a poor job, orthogonal least squares does no better. I tried a few other models with no success. I have been able to visually inspect the trend and select some of the ~2s, perform a linear regression, and then subtract the bias. I would like to programmatically do this across many data sets, so a  generic way to do this reliability is essential.  Any ideas on how to detrend the data and remove the bias?

Actual data: [data](https://github.com/bkief/python-hipster/blob/master/data.txt)

Comment: What about working with first differences?

Comment: What do you mean by "...does a poor job"?

Comment: When you say "orthogonal" do you mean "ordinal"? Have you tried an ordinal model? Can you provide a sample data set that answerers could play with?

Comment: The notion of detrending really only makes sense when you can additively decompose the data, e.g. in the simplest case as 'data = trend + noise'. That makes sense when you have continuous data that's not too skew. When you have small counts (say), such a decomposition doesn't really make sense. You can still *estimate* some kind of trend, but the additive residual doesn't necessarily carry much useful meaning.

Comment: In the example (because the trend is not too steep), taking differences modulo $1$ and dividing by the differences in $X$ will produce a constant set of values, all equal to the trend.  If all your data will look like this example, that's all the analysis necessary and no probability model is needed.

Comment: By poor job I mean, OLS did not effectively capture the bias and thusly I could not subtract it out. By othogonal least squares I mean http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares

Comment: I added a least to some real data at the end of my question. Unfortunately my data is highly unlikely to be integer and is closely spaced, making the modulus technique difficult. The only viable idea I have at the moment is to write an algorithm to adjust the linear coefficients of the bias model to minimize number of unique y-values. That seems a little brute force, but I was hoping there is a statistical method for this. The pattern is plain as day to my eyes, its just hard to express it mathematically.

Comment: If the number of points n is quite large compared to the number $p$ of groups, calculate the slopes of all $\tbinom{n}{2}$ paires (or a subsample if $n$ is too large) and look at their distribution. The mode gives you the time trend, since at least $100/p \%$ of all pairs will have the same slope and the other slopes are quite random.